# Xcode UI Tests : xcodebuild fails to generate Coverage.profdata on xcode12, fails with error 'error: No profiles could be merged.'

Tags: ios, jenkins, code-coverage, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing

Here is how we are setup while facing the issue.

- We have a project which has both UI and Unit tests.
- Uses fastlane.
- Has CI/CD implementation using Jenkins which runs on an aws ec2 instance.
- Quite recently we moved to Xcode12 (I know!!! However, better late than never)

**Problem statement:**

After moving to xcode12, the jenkins pipeline is unable to generate the `Coverage.profdata` file which in turn will be used by `Slather` to derive code coverage metrics. Yes, did not happen when running xcode11.

We are using the `xcodebuild` command after pointing it to the appropriate command line tool version (in this case it is 12.4).

First we build the app using (after getting the simulator ID)

```
xcodebuild build-for-testing -workspace Example.xcworkspace -scheme ExampleUITests -derivedDataPath ./derivedData -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=<simulator_id>'
```

Then we run the test using

```
xcodebuild test-without-building -workspace Example.xcworkspace -scheme ExampleUITests -enableCodeCoverage YES -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=<simulator_id>' -derivedDataPath ./derivedData
```

All the UI tests run successfully but end up with the following statements when the test suite completes.

```
warning: <Path_to_derived_data>/Build/ProfileData/<Some_UUID>/<Filename>.profraw: Invalid instrumentation profile data (file header is corrupt)
error: No profiles could be merged.
```

*P.S: This is not happening on my local machine. Only on the mac in the Jenkins ec2 instance.*

Comment: Have you tried with the xcov plugin with fastlane?

Comment: So in this instance we are not using fastlane, As you can see it is the xcodebuild command. It is not that i cannot use it but we are running it as a part of a templated infra and this is what is executed while running the tests.

Comment: Okay, actually xcodebuild generates the Coverage.profdata on its own under <Path_to_derived_data>/Build/ProfileData/<Some_UUID>/Coverage.profdata. This I can assure you as we using it in our custom scripts to generate the reports.

Comment: @SachinVas... Yes that is the expected situation but the error i am facing as i have mentioned above is that Coverage.profdata is not being generated due to the xcodebuild command facing issue's merging/generating .profraw files. BTW this happens only on Xcode 12 and on a Jenkins env. Same setup run from Xcode  11 on the same env works fine.

Comment: I am just curios, who is running the merge command to generate Coverage.profdata?

Comment: I think it is the xcodebuild command itself. No other commands are being executed apart from this.

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar issue. We were also using fastlane.

And the fix which worked for us was to ensure we delete any artifacts from the previous build. The situation you've described is quite similar to situation we faced. The first run for unit tests generates a few coverage artifacts, after which executing UI tests also generates coverage artifacts and then xcov/slather is unable to parse these artifacts.

Therefore, can you check if deleting the `Logs/Test` folder in derived data helps? If it doesn't try clearing derived data entirely and then check if that helps resolve the issue on CI.

See [related threads](https://github.com/fastlane-community/xcov/issues/187) [on xcov](https://github.com/fastlane-community/danger-xcov/issues/33#issuecomment-704510403)